# How to print the hierarchy of views in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am adding some views & their subviews through code.I have added some subviews in a main views,now i want to print the hierarchy of views in which order they are added.Please tell me how can i print the hierarchy of view in iOS?

Comment: They are doing through story board.I want to do it by code.

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question explains the -recursiveDescription method, this is the correct approach regardless of whether views were added in code or in a storyboard.